# How to use if else statement inside select new

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of ***FlightTicketRequestDocument*** used for both Patients and their Escorts requesting a plane ticket. Theses are grouped with a `GUID` named *GroupId*.

I'm trying to group them inside this object:

```cs
public class FlightTicketRequestDocumentGroup
{
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    public FlightTicketRequestDocument PrincipalDocument { get; set; }
    public List<FlightTicketRequestDocument> GroupDocuments { get; set; }
}
```

***PrincipalDocument* holds the Patient if there's one.** (If there isn't we just want the first Escort)

***GroupDocuments* holds the Escorts.** (Except the first one that is placed in *PrincipalDocument*)

---

I'm attempting to use different expressions to set my values inside a `Select New` statement depending if there's a Patient or not but I'm getting the error:

> *The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case' Operation2='VarRef'*

Here's the code (Note: ***StayEscortId* is null when the person is a Patient.**):

```cs
var indexGroups = await _db.FlightTicketRequests
                .OrderBy(f => f.FirstName)
                .ProjectTo<FlightTicketRequestDocument>()
                .GroupBy(f => f.GroupId)
                .Select(g => new FlightTicketRequestDocumentGroup
                {
                    GroupId = g.Key,
                    PrincipalDocument = g.Any(f => f.StayEscortId == null)
                                                        ? g.FirstOrDefault(f => f.StayEscortId == null)
                                                        : g.FirstOrDefault(),
                    GroupDocuments = g.Any(f => f.StayEscortId == null)
                                                        ? g.Where(c => c.StayEscortId != null).ToList()
                                                        : g.Where(c => c.StayEscortId != null).OrderBy(f => f.FullName).Skip(1).ToList()
                })
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

What can I use instead of the conditional operator `?:` ?

Comment: Could `g.Any(f => f.StayEscortId == null)
                                                        ? g.FirstOrDefault(f => f.StayEscortId == null)
                                                        : g.FirstOrDefault(),` instead be `g.OrderBy(f => f.StayEscortId != null).FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: That should naturally ensure that the `null` values are prioritised (which appears to be what you are trying to do), since `false` will sort before `true`.

Comment: Aren't you missing parenthesis : .Select(g => new FlightTicketRequestDocumentGroup() {......})

Comment: @jdweng I have a vague feeling that isn't necessary if you are using object initializers. I could be wrong.

Comment: For giggles what happens if you add .ToList() to `GroupBy(f => f.GroupId)`?

Comment: That error is generated by whatever software implements the query pattern in your case; you're going to have to ask whoever wrote that software for advice on what kinds of queries they support and do not support.

Comment: What is the type of the value returned by `ProjectTo`?

Comment: @EricLippert It projects *FlightTicketRequests* into a *FlightTicketREquestDocumentGroup*. This is not important for my problem tho.

Comment: it is extremely important for your problem in all likelihood. Is it IQueryable?

Comment: @EricLippert Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution that I ended up using:**

As specified by @mjwills, since I simply want the values where *StayEscordId* is `null` first, all I need to do is to sort as a `boolean` (`false` values end up at the top).

For the rest of the group, I do the same operation while Skipping 1 (the first one I chose).

**Modified code:**

```cs
var indexGroups = await _db.FlightTicketRequests
                .OrderBy(f => f.FirstName)
                .ProjectTo<FlightTicketRequestDocument>()
                .GroupBy(f => f.GroupId)
                .Select(g => new FlightTicketRequestDocumentGroup
                {
                    GroupId = g.Key,
                    PrincipalDocument = g.OrderBy(f => f.StayEscortId != null).ThenBy(f => f.FullName).FirstOrDefault(),
                    GroupDocuments = g.OrderBy(f => f.StayEscortId != null).ThenBy(f => f.FullName).Skip(1).ToList()
                })
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what the query would look like if you were to use if/else instead of the ternary conditions. You would just use a code block inside of the `.Select()` to return the results:

```
var flightTicketRequestDocuments = await _db.FlightTicketRequests
    .OrderBy(f => f.FirstName)
    .ProjectTo<FlightTicketRequestDocument>()
    .GroupBy(f => f.GroupId)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

var indexGroups = flightTicketRequestDocuments
    .Select(g =>
    {
        FlightTicketRequestDocument principalDocument;
        List<FlightTicketRequestDocument> groupDocuments;

        if (g.Any(f => f.StayEscortId == null))
        {
            principalDocument = g.FirstOrDefault(f => f.StayEscortId == null);
            groupDocuments = g.Where(c => c.StayEscortId != null).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            principalDocument = g.FirstOrDefault();
            groupDocuments = g.Where(c => c.StayEscortId != null).OrderBy(f => f.FullName).Skip(1).ToList();
        }

        return new FlightTicketRequestDocumentGroup 
        { 
            GroupId = g.Key, 
            PrincipalDocument = principalDocument,
            GroupDocuments = groupDocuments 
        };
    }) 
    .ToList();
```

---

Note that this approach requires enumerating the `IQueryable` *before* performing the `.Select()` so that it's applied against an [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__).

Comment: This isn't a LINQ-to-objects situation; you can't use statements as expression trees.

Answer (score -1):

Needs a check or two (or a tweak or two) but if i remember correctly expression trees accept null coalescence operator you may try to swap in the place of the ternary.
Starting (and BASING) from your example, maybe something like the following?

```
var indexGroups = await _db.FlightTicketRequests
                .OrderBy(f => f.FirstName)
                .ProjectTo<FlightTicketRequestDocument>()
                .GroupBy(f => f.GroupId)
                .Select(g => new FlightTicketRequestDocumentGroup
                {
                    GroupId = g.Key,
                    PrincipalDocument = g.FirstOrDefault(f => f.StayEscortId == null) ?? g.OrderBy(f => f.FullName).FirstOrDefault(),
                    GroupDocuments = g.Where(c => c.StayEscortId != null).OrderBy(f => f.FullName).Skip(Math.Max(x.Count(y => y.StayEscortId == null), 1)).ToList()
                })
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```